# Ubuntu Software Center won't work at all

Tags: software-center

Ubuntu software center was being weird with me before, it wouldn't open up in the  Dash and I couldn't open it up properly in terminal without something going wrong.

I googled the problem and people recommended the usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This didn't work.

So then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center


me@me-computer:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
[sudo] password for sonney: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apport
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 19                 not to upgrade.
164 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/535 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] me@me-computer:~$
```

suggesting that software-center is already on my computer. However when i type in

```
software-center
```

I get

```
sonney@sonney-UX32A:~$ software-center
bash: /usr/bin/software-center: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me please? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Edit: To New USer:

I ran

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

to get a fairly large list

```
/usr/bin/python            /usr/bin/python3               /usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/python2           /usr/bin/python3.4          /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python3.4-config   /usr/bin/python3m-config
/usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3.4m         /usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2-config    /usr/bin/python3.4m-config  /usr/bin/pythonSAVE
```

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`

Comment: What happens with the command: `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/software-center`? If that doesn't work, what is the output of `which python`? Also what happens if you just enter `python` on the command line (if the interpreter does appear you can exit with Ctrl+D).

Comment: @TheSchwa `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/software-center` returns `bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`. `which python` returns `/usr/local/bin/python` and `python` opens python stating `Python 2.7.5 (default, Dec 30 2014, 22:28:34) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2`

Comment: Huh...have you ever messed with your python installation? As New USer noticed there's some sort of problem with your script symlinks. What is the output of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/python`? And also the output of `update-alternatives --display python`? I probably have a solution but I want to make sure I understand what your current setup is doing.

Comment: @TheSchwa, I've been trying to play around with Ubuntu for a couple of months,  I had problems in the beginning installing python packages, as my stupid self didn't have virtualenvironment set up at the time (or know about it for that matter), I'm sure some serious damage has been caused. Running ` ls -l /etc/alternatives/python` returns `ls: cannot access /etc/alternatives/python: No such file or directory` and `update-alternatives --display python` returns `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python`

Answer (score 1):

It seems broken symlink of python in /usr/bin.

```
 ls -l /usr/bin/python
```

list all the python binaries available.

Then simply creat a symlink with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: I tried to implement your changes, please see the edit (I didn't know you could use code in comments until just now)

Comment: What is the output of `python --version?`

Comment: check the edit now

Comment: Python 2.7.5,  shall i perform the commands in your edit now?

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3` returns `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/python3’: File exists`

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`

Comment: `ln -l /usr/bin/python` returns `ln: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'ln --help' for more information.`

Comment: Sry typo error its' `ls -l` not `ln -l`

Comment: which returns `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Apr  7 03:32 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python`

Comment: ok now do `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: returning `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/python’: File exists` or did you mean ls?

Comment: no its ln... ok now try again what happens?

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python` returns `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/python’: File exists` . I just ran it again

Comment: I mean run t he sofwtare center again

Comment: `software-center` returns the same as before:  `bash: /usr/bin/software-center: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, also clicking on the icon on the dash home does nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `software-center` starts with the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/python` which apparently points to a non-existent file on your system. I'm assuming absolute paths are common for Ubuntu default programs, rather than the more commonly used by developers `#!/usr/bin/env python` which would default to the first entry on your path (potentially incompatible).

This should work based on the output in your comments:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

If that doesn't work you could also try re-configuring python which should (hopefully) fix your script links:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure python
```

I'm not sure if completely re-installing is a good idea, since alot of stuff in Ubuntu depends on Python, but that's also an option:

```
sudo apt-get remove python
sudo apt-get install python
```

If that still doesn't work add an `apt-get autoremove` and try `purge` instead of `remove` to make sure *everything* goes away. Be careful using `autoremove` though, it can have unexpected consequences depending on the state of your packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge python
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install python
```

Comment: I tried everything that you wrote, and everything related to python was deleted, then i `sudo apt-get install python` and finally `sudo apt-get install software-center`,  while this is happening, some errors popped up but i was unable to report the problem, it also returned an error: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
` Finally,  I tried `software-center`, but that didn't work either, the same errors popped up as last time :(

Comment: Since everything is gone anyway, should i just start again? completely reboot my linux after backing up?